# How to Write a Makefile when Source and Include are in Subdirectories

Tags: c, makefile, linker

I have a project structured like so

```
project
|
|__build
|
|
|__include
|  |
|  |
|  |__modules
|  |  |
|  |  |_module1
|  |    |
|  |    |_ foo.h
|  |
|  |_ bar.h
|
|__src
|  |
|  |__modules
|  |  |
|  |  |_module1
|  |    |
|  |    |_ foo.c
|  |
|  |__main.c
|
|__Makefile
```

And my current Makefile is

```
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -std=gnu11 -O3 -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -Wstrict-aliasing
LDFLAGS = -lpthread

INC = include/
BLD = build
SRC = src

define cc-command
$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -I $(INC) $< -o $@
endef
enter code here
all: main
main: build/main.o
    $(CC) -o $@ $^ $(LDFLAGS)
$(BLD)/%.o: $(SRC)/%.c
    $(cc-command)
```

And my main.c has a bit saying

```
#include "modules/module1/foo.h"
// Other things
int main()
{
    foo_function();    // Defined in foo.c, declared in foo.h
    // The other things...
```

When I run make, it returns "undefined reference to 'foo_function'"

I feel like my rule for building the .o files is wrong, but I don't know in what way. I'd really appreciate getting a bit of a nudge in the right direction on it. Maybe I need a separate rule for building each module's .o files, and a rule for building main.o?

Comment: Where are you linking with `foo.o`?

Comment: You need build/foo.o to be in the list of inputs to the final link

Comment: ah that would do it! Is there a way to list the .o files to link, in a generic way so I don't need to specify each of them explicitly?

Comment: You must *somehow* tell Make which object files to link. It could be by an explicit list, or by something like *"everything in `src/`".*

Comment: You could shell out and replace the suffix and path by pattern substitution: `$(patsubst $(SRC)%, $(BLD)%, $(patsubst %.c,%.o, $(shell find $(SRC) -name *.c)))` (not tested)